# Following the steps to implement Laravel native mail verification bring to an issue

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, email-verification, jenssegers-mongodb

Following the guide to implement the native mail verification of laravel.
Brings me an error.

Note please that i use MongoDB, therefore i'm using Jensseger/laravel-mongodb package

This is the error:
`Class App\User contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail::hasVerifiedEmail, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail::markEmailAsVerified, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail::sendEmailVerificationNotification`

I've already try to implement the methods inside my model and they seem to solve the problem. But it won't send any emails.

Here's what i've implemented im my User.php model

```
    * Determine if the user has verified their email address.
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function hasVerifiedEmail()
    {}

    /**
    * Mark the given user's email as verified.
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function markEmailAsVerified()
    {}

    /**
    * Send the email verification notification.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {}
```

Here's my User.php model

```
namespace App;

use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
```

Here's my web.php route file.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

And here's my HomeController.php

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth','verified']);
    }
```

Here's my env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Like this the project work but it wont send emails. Do i need to put the logic inside the three method inside the User.php? If yes what should i put in it? I've no idea because if it's native and work like charm with SQL i don't really know how to get it work on my project
Hope someone has a solution for this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to implement trait `Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail` which should be there, however it is not mentioned in the Laravel documentation. You can also override these methods by defining them in the model as you did. But `hasVerifiedEmail` and `markEmailAsVerified` methods should have some verification logic and return `bool` based on [the API](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.html).

**Edit**:
I also forgot to mention that method `sendEmailVerificationNotification` should contain `$this->notify(new Notifications\VerifyEmail);` otherwise it won't use the Notifiable trait and thus not send any email. For more details take a look at the method in [Laravel framework repository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.php),

Comment: Hi @Silencesys, thanks for answering. If using Contracts\Auth\ etc\MustverifyEmail and the one that you mentioned (illuminate\Auth\MistVerifyEmail) which one should I implement? Anyway if you go to the file that you mentioned, it is an interface and not a trait, so it’s impossible to use it in the model. Do you have suggestion how to complete the logic methods ?

Comment: Hello, both files that I mentioned are traits - I checked them again. I would suggest implementing both, the trait and the interface. You can import the trait like `use Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail as MustVerifyEmailTrait` and then use it in your User model. Or if you don't like this idea, you can implement or rather copy-paste content of the MustVerifyEmail trait to your model [see the trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/MustVerifyEmail.php) on Laravel Github.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. It worked with only implementing those two files in my model :)